# Datetime still showing time component

Tags: python, pandas

I have this line of code-

```
future_end_date = datetime.strptime('2020/02/29','%Y/%m/%d')
```

and when I print this-

```
2020-02-29 00:00:00
```

it still shows the time component even though I did `strptime`

Answer (score 0):

This is because strptime returns datetime rather than date. Try converting it to date:

```
datetime.strptime('2020/02/29','%Y/%m/%d').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime) function returns a datetime
>   object corresponding to `date_string`, parsed according to format.
>   When you print datetime object, it is formatted as a string in ISO
>   8601 format, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

So you need to convert the datetime into date if you  only want Year, month and Day -

```
datetime.strptime('2020/02/29','%Y/%m/%d').date()
```

---

Another possible way is using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime) method which returns a string representing date and time using date, time or datetime object.

```
datetime.strptime('2020/02/29','%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Output of both code snippets -

```
2020/02/29
```